# How to add Class in <li> using wp_nav_menu() in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-nav-walker, wp-nav-menu-item

I am using `wp_nav_menu($args)` and I want to add `my_own_class` CSS classname to the `<li>` element.

I'd like to get the following result:

```php
<li class='my_own_class'><a href=''>Link</a>
```

How to do that?

Comment: This function is very well documented, but it appears a lot easier to add a class to the ul or wrap the link content with something and change your CSS accordingly (custom walker is you alternative): http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Or..you could create your own Menu Walker ( [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) ) and use it in your `wp_nav_menu()` function..

Answer (score -26, accepted):

You can't add a class directly to the LIs very easily, but is there any reason not to target them in a slightly different but equally specific way (by their parent ul)?

You can set the class or ID of the menu with the menu_class and menu_id parameters (affixed to the UL parent of the LIs) and then target the li's via CSS that way, like so:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu('menu_id=mymenu'); ?>
```

And for CSS:

```
ul#mymenu li {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

Edit: At the time of writing in 2013 this was the easiest way to add it, but updates since then have added the feature to add CSS classes directly in the admin navigation editor.  See more recent answers for details.

Comment: While I appreciate the attempt to propose a solution this doesn't answer the question. In my case, for example, I need to apply a Bootstrap 4 "col" class.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is use JS.  Otherwise you need to add a filter via PHP that modifies the core function as detailed in one of the other answers.

Comment: I know this is old, but it's equally unhelpful in my situation and doesn't address the original question.  In my situation, I'm trying to target a menu item by name, within a network install where the menu list item ID's vary between sites.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - see the other upvoted answers for alternative ways to handle this.

Comment: This might not be the best way to solve the problem, but its a perfectly valid answer.  There are almost always multiple ways to solve any problem and every potential solution has pros and cons.  I'm not sure why this answer is getting so much hate.

Answer (score 173):

No need to create custom walker. Just use additional argument and set filter for nav_menu_css_class.

For example:

```
$args = array(
    'container'     => '',
    'theme_location'=> 'your-theme-loc',
    'depth'         => 1,
    'fallback_cb'   => false,
    'add_li_class'  => 'your-class-name1 your-class-name-2'
    );
wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Notice the new 'add_li_class' argument.

And set the filter on functions.php

```
function add_additional_class_on_li($classes, $item, $args) {
    if(isset($args->add_li_class)) {
        $classes[] = $args->add_li_class;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_additional_class_on_li', 1, 3);
```

Comment: Nice solution. If I was the OP, I would have accepted this as the answer.

Comment: Best solution IMO, generic and clean

Comment: Best solution, but I need to modify it to avoid an error "Undefined property: stdClass::$item_class"

**Solution**: if(isset($args->item_class)) { ...etc

Comment: what is the function of 1 and 3 argument? Please Explain.

Comment: 1 is the priority order. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

3 is the number of arguments the function accepts. On that case, the filter will accept $classes, $items and $args arguments.

Please read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ for more information

Comment: This didn't work for me. Instead of `isset($args->add_li_class)` I had to add `array_key_exists('add_li_class', $args)`. And for `$classes[] = $args->add_li_class;` I had to add `$classes[] = $args['add_li_class'];`.

Answer (score 76):

You can add a filter for the `nav_menu_css_class` action in your functions.php file.

Example:

```
function atg_menu_classes($classes, $item, $args) {
  if($args->theme_location == 'secondary') {
    $classes[] = 'list-inline-item';
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'atg_menu_classes', 1, 3);
```

Docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/

Comment: I know this answer was published much later than the chosen one, but I feel this should be marked as the correct answer as it does exactly what the question asked.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, directly copied into my functions.php and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @SpencerShattuck do you have a menu location 'secondary' in your theme? You may also need something like 

<code>
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu' )
    )
);
</code>

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me at: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

Answer (score 69):

HERE [WordPress add custom class in wp_nav_menu links](https://sdtuts.com/wordpress-add-custom-class-in-wp_nav_menu-links/)

OR 
you can add class  `<li class='my_own_class'><a href=''>Link</a></li>`  from admin panel:

1. Go to `YOURSITEURL/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`
2. open  `SCREEN OPTIONS`
3. make checked `CSS CLASSES`, then you will see `CSS Classes (optional)`
   field in each menu link.

Comment: This is the answer OP.

Comment: this has to be done by end user. not a solution to implement in theme.

Comment: For dev it's the best and easy one as if they are developing static themes.

Comment: for huge menus, this is not a practical solution

Answer (score 17):

Adding Class to `<li>` tag without editing `functions.php` file:

1. Go to Appearance -> Menu -> Screen Options -> CSS Classes
2. You will get CSS Class option enabled in `Menu Items` Window

[image]

Answer (score 15):

use this filter `nav_menu_css_class` as shown below

```
function add_classes_on_li($classes, $item, $args) {
    $classes[] = 'nav-item';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_classes_on_li',1,3);
```

**UPDATE**

To use this filter with specific menu

```
if ( 'main-menu' === $args->theme_location ) { //replace main-menu with your menu
    $classes[] = "nav-item"; 
}
```

Comment: But how to we target specific menus with this approach. I have a menu called main-menu and another called footer-menu.

Comment: try wrapping `$classes[] = "nav-item";` with  `if ( 'main-menu' === $args->theme_location ) {
        $classes[] = "nav-item";
    }`

Answer (score 6):

How about just using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function, if you just want to "Add Classes":

```
<?php
    echo str_replace( '<li class="', '<li class="myclass ',
        wp_nav_menu(
            array(
                'theme_location'    => 'main_menu',
                'container'         => false,
                'items_wrap'        => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'             => 1,
                'echo'              => false
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

Tough it is a quick fix for one-level menus or the menus that you want to add Classes to all of `<li>` elements and is not recommended for more complex menus

Comment: Good idea for those whom don't use a standard `<li>` as items.

Answer (score 3):

None of these responses really seem to answer the question.  Here's something similar to what I'm utilizing on a site of mine by targeting a menu item by its title/name:

```
function add_class_to_menu_item($sorted_menu_objects, $args) {
    $theme_location = 'primary_menu';  // Name, ID, or Slug of the target menu location
    $target_menu_title = 'Link';  // Name/Title of the menu item you want to target
    $class_to_add = 'my_own_class';  // Class you want to add

    if ($args->theme_location == $theme_location) {
        foreach ($sorted_menu_objects as $key => $menu_object) {
            if ($menu_object->title == $target_menu_title) {
                $menu_object->classes[] = $class_to_add;
                break; // Optional.  Leave if you're only targeting one specific menu item
            }
        }
    }

    return $sorted_menu_objects;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_class_to_menu_item', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

I added a class to easily implement menu arguments. So you can customize and include in your function like this:

```
include_once get_template_directory() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "your-directory" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "Menu.php";

<?php $menu = (new Menu('your-theme-location'))
            ->setMenuClass('your-menu')
            ->setMenuID('your-menu-id')
            ->setListClass('your-menu-class')
            ->setLinkClass('your-menu-link anchor') ?>
    
            // Print your menu
            <?php $menu->showMenu() ?>
```

```
<?php

class Menu
{
    private $args = [
        'theme_location' => '',
        'container' => '',
        'menu_id' => '',
        'menu_class' => '',
        'add_li_class' => '',
        'link_class' => ''
    ];

    public function __construct($themeLocation)
    {
        add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', [$this,'add_additional_class_on_li'], 1, 3);
        add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', [$this,'add_menu_link_class'], 1, 3 );

        $this->args['theme_location'] = $themeLocation;
    }

    public function wrapWithTag($tagName){
        $this->args['container'] = $tagName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setMenuID($id)
    {
        $this->args['menu_id'] = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setMenuClass($class)
    {
        $this->args['menu_class'] = $class;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setListClass($class)
    {
        $this->args['add_li_class'] = $class;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setLinkClass($class)
    {
        $this->args['link_class'] = $class;
        return $this;
    }

    public function showMenu()
    {
        return wp_nav_menu($this->args);
    }

    function add_additional_class_on_li($classes, $item, $args) {
        if(isset($args->add_li_class)) {
            $classes[] = $args->add_li_class;
        }
        return $classes;
    }

    function add_menu_link_class( $atts, $item, $args ) {
        if (property_exists($args, 'link_class')) {
            $atts['class'] = $args->link_class;
        }
        return $atts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    echo preg_replace( '#<li[^>]+>#', '<li class="col-sm-4">',
            wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'menu' => $nav_menu, 
                        'container'  => false,
                        'container_class'   => false,
                        'menu_class'        => false,
                        'items_wrap'        => '%3$s',
                                            'depth'             => 1,
                                            'echo'              => false
                            )
                    )
            );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use `wp_nav_menu_items` to [Filters the HTML list content for navigation menus.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/)

Display nav menu

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
   'theme_location' => 'parimary',
   'container' => 'ul',
   'menu_class'=> 'nav col-12 col-md-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0',
   'add_li_class'  => 'your-class-name1 your-class-name-2',
) );
```

Menu Registration

```
function thesportworship_register_menus(){
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'  => __( 'Main Menu', 'thesportworship' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'thesportworship_register_menus', 0 );
```

Apply filter

```
function add_additional_class($classes, $item, $args){
    if(isset($args->add_li_class)){
        $classes[] = $args->add_li_class;
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_additional_class', 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple way to call *"li"* calss and "any class" replace easily. Just follow the instructions.

Use this code in the nav area.

```
<?php
            $consult_menu = wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location' => 'topmenu',
                    'menu_id' => 'menu',
                    'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav m-auto',
                    'echo' => false
                )
            );
            $consult_menu = str_replace('menu-item', 'nav-item', $consult_menu);
            echo $consult_menu;
            ?>
```

Then inspect your code on the browser. find wp default class and than replace *"str_replace(**"default_class_here"**,**"new_li_class_here"**,$consult_menu);*
| **Note:** ***$consult_menu*** here is my theme name, you can use any name here.

Answer (score 0):

The correct one for me is the Zuan solution. Be aware to add isset to `$args->add_li_class` , however you got `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$add_li_class` if you haven't set the property in all yours `wp_nav_menu()` functions.

This is the function that worked for me:

```
function add_additional_class_on_li($classes, $item, $args) {
    if(isset($args->add_li_class)) {
      $classes[] = $args->add_li_class;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_additional_class_on_li', 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

// Remove translation from Main Menu

```
function wpdocs_channel_nav_class($classes, $item, $args){
{

if ('primary' === $args->theme_location) {
    $classes[] = "notranslate";
}
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'wpdocs_channel_nav_class', 10, 4);
```

This is how you easily add the new class to existing class array of you Menu wrapp

Answer (score 0):

This is how I added the MainMenu of the WordPress and class to li.

```
<?php
        $defaults = array( 'menu' => 'mainmenu', 
        'container' => false, 
        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="navbar-nav" id="myTab">%3$s</ul>', 
        'add_li_class'  => 'nav-item',
       'theme_location' => 'mainmenu' );
        wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

Use this code in functions.php

```
function li_new_class($classes, $item, $args) {
if(isset($args->add_li_class)) {
    $classes[] = $args->add_li_class;
}
return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_li_class', 'li_new_class', 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom walker class

```
class Custom_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        // Add custom class to the <ul> at this level
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu-level-$depth\">\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        // Add custom class to each <li> item
        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
        $class_names = ' class="'.esc_attr($class_names).'"';

        $output .= $indent.'<li id="menu-item-'.$item->ID.'"'.$value.$class_names.'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->title ) ? esc_attr( $item->title ) : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? esc_attr( $item->target ) : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? esc_attr( $item->xfn ) : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url ) ? esc_attr( $item->url ) : '';

        $atts = apply_filters('nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args);

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ('href' === $attr) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);

        // You can add more customizations or classes as needed
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        // Add custom closing tag for the <ul> at this level
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    // Add this method to fix the compatibility issue
    function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        // Add custom closing tag for the <li> item
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

then use it

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'walker' => new Custom_Menu_Walker())) ?>
```

This custom walker also indicates deep level of menu list e.g "sub-menu-level-0" and so on...

[image]