# How can I add class to <a href> wp_nav_menu?

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 menu. How can I add class to a href for 'header_menu'? Thanks

```
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header_menu'      => 'Header menu',
            'header_menu_page' => 'Menu Page'           

        )
    );
}
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_menus' );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add class to link in wp\_nav\_menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180688/how-to-add-class-to-link-in-wp-nav-menu)

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: is it solved ? @Nikita

Comment: Great to hear. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call a class in header menu.

```
function register_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header_menu'      => '<div class="ClassName"'.'Header menu'.'</div>',
            'header_menu_page' => 'Menu Page'           

        )
    );
}
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_menus' );
```