# Add class to anchors in WordPress Menus

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add the standard Bootstrap `nav-link` class to the anchors rendered by the WordPress menu.

1. I can pass variables to the `wp_nav_menu()` which applies a class to the menu (and remove the containing):

   ```
   <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
       'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
       'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav',
       'container' => 'false'
   ) );
   ?>
   ```
2. I then use the WordPress Appearances > Menu UI to apply `nav-item` class to `<li>` tags.

How do I apply a class to the WordPress menu anchor tags?

Comment: To avoid adding classes in the menu UI you can use the 'nav_menu_css_class'. I'll add this to my answer...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do what you need with the WP `nav_menu_link_attributes` hook:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function($atts) {
        $atts['class'] = "nav-link";
        return $atts;
}, 100, 1 );
```

...or if you don't like closures:

```
function add_link_atts($atts) {
  $atts['class'] = "nav-link";
  return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_link_atts');
```

### Filter menu list items

To avoid using the WordPress menu UI to add classes to the menu list items, you can take advantage of the 'nav_menu_css_class' filter:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', function($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'nav-item';
    return $classes;
}, 10, 1 );
```

Comment: those filters doesn't appear in wordpress' filter hooks reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference. Sure they exist?

Comment: nav_menu_link_attributes has worked, I haven't yet tried nav_menu_css_class

Comment: @127.0.0.1 Yep, they exist! Check out `wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php` lines 136 and 179

Comment: Glad it worked @TimothyAURA, please consider marking the answer correct.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll look after work. If they do count with my upvote. Its nice to have such things, although they not always are documented :( --EDIT: Ok, i'll take TimothyAURA's word.

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

Comment: DavidCara: feel free to /msg stobrendo through freenode :). (Its me).

Comment: The problem with this, for me, is, it seems to *remove* classes WordPress is itself applying, like "active", which means I cannot style for the active menu item.

Comment: Would there be a way to get/set a value for $atts['class'] from wp_nav_menu $arg, rather than hard-coding it ?

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Mate.

Comment: I have a better solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67859550/9207553

Comment: I have a better solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67859550/9207553

Comment: Care this answer is BAD, the other answer by Lars Flieger is not hard coded and thus a way better solution than this!

Answer (score 13):

If you have multiple menus over your site or just want to be flexible. You can extend the `wp_nav_menu` build-in function:

Just add `add_a_class` to your `wp_nav_menu` function:

```php
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location'  => 'primary',
        'depth'           => 2,
        'container'       => 'div',
        'add_a_class'     => 'class1 class2',
        'fallback_cb'     => false,
    )
);
```

Add the following code in your `functions.php`:

```php
function add_additional_class_on_a($classes, $item, $args)
{
    if (isset($args->add_a_class)) {
        $classes['class'] = $args->add_a_class;
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_additional_class_on_a', 1, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

This allows you to add classes **ONLY** to anchors of **SPECIFIC MENU**. Just add your classes into `$menuClassMap` values below.

```
    function mytheme__menu_anchors_add_css( $atts, $item, $args ) {

        $menuClassMap = [
            'navbar-menu' => 'my-footer-menu-link-class',
            'footer-menu' => 'my-footer-menu-link-class',
        ];

        $additionalClassName = $menuClassMap[$args->menu->slug] ?? '';

        if($additionalClassName){
            if(!array_key_exists('class', $atts)){
                $atts['class'] = '';
            }
            $classList = explode (' ' , $atts['class']);
            $classList[] = $additionalClassName;
            $atts['class'] = implode (' ' , $classList);
        }
        return $atts;

    }

    add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'mytheme__menu_anchors_add_css', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

[wp_nav_menu()'s parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters)  wont allow you to add a class to your links with default's functionality. It would allow you to enclose your `<a href="#"></a>` within any html like `<span class="wrapped-anchor"><a href="#"></a></span>` if you use :

```
<?php 
   $parameters = TimothyAURA->set_specific_parameters_you_want(); // i mean, realy fullfill the array with the options you want based on the docs.
   $parameters['before'] = '<span class="wrapped-anchor">';
   $parameters['after'] = '</span>';
   wp_nav_menu($parameters);
```

In case you really **need** to set a class for your anchors you would have to pass a Walker object. You would need to read and understand [this specific docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) about it, though.

Comment: not a good solution. I have a much better solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67859550/9207553

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class in anchor tag for a specific menu then can use following steps

Step-1: add this in functions.php

```
function add_class_on_a_tag($classes, $item, $args)
{
    if (isset($args->add_a_class)) {
        $classes['class'] = $args->add_a_class;
    }
return $classes;
}

add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_on_a_tag', 1, 3);
```

Step-2:-  use it like this in your theme

```
<?php
    // Show Menu here
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'my-menu',
        'menu_class'      => 'footer-top',
        'add_a_class'     => 'nav-link',
    ));
?>
```

Comment: nope, copy/paste from other answers.