# Add custom classes to navigation menu items - Twenty Twenty Three theme, WordPress

Tags: wordpress

So with the new *TT3* theme, doesn't look like we can use `nav_menu_css_class` filter anymore to add custom classes to menu items (`<li>`) or `nav_menu_link_attributes` for the anchors (`<a>`) like we did before:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', function ($classes){
  $classes[] = 'custom-nav-item';
  return $classes;
}, 10 , 2);

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function($atts) {
  $atts['class'] = 'custom-nav-link';
  return $atts;
}, 100, 1 );
```

likely because menus are now created via the new *Customize->Editor* and don't fire the hook which was a formerly initiated by a hardcoded `wp_nav_menu` in theme template files.

Has anyone figured out how to add custom classes to menu items in *twentytwentythree*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress Menu - Add class to anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994156/wordpress-menu-add-class-to-anchors)

Comment: Just to double check, your code uses `‘` instead of `'` which will cause PHP errors. Can you check that the code in your question matches that in your website?

Comment: @KirkBeard No, the filter `nav_menu_link_attributes` also doesn't run when the menu is created with the new _Customize->Editor_

Comment: @KirkBeard correct ticks were used in code, just copying/pasting somehow changed them to the other type. And `<li>` targeting is now specified since I don't need to touch `<a>` of the menu items. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the nav_menu_css_class and nav_menu_link_attributes filters are not used in the new Customize->Editor method of creating menus in the Twenty Twenty Three theme for WordPress.

Comment: However, you can still add custom classes to menu items using the nav_menu_item_classes filter. Here's an example of how to do it: `add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_classes', function( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    $classes[] = 'custom-nav-item';
    return $classes;
}, 10, 4 );`

Comment: This code adds the 'custom-nav-item' class to all menu items.

Similarly, you can add custom attributes to the menu item's anchor using the nav_menu_link_attributes filter, like so:  `add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    $atts['class'] = 'custom-nav-link';
    return $atts;
}, 10, 4 );`This code adds the 'custom-nav-link' class to all menu item links.

Comment: @user21354674 thanks, but filters `nav_menu_item_classes` and `nav_menu_link_attributes` also don't run in this case (can't find documentation for `nav_menu_item_classes` online either)