# Print WordPress menu in a tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some WordPress nav menus and I want to print each nav menu under an `<a>` tag. I tried the following code:

```php
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'menu'           => 'Main Menu',
            'theme_location' => 'api-footer-main',
            'menu_class'     => 'hex__footer_link', 
            'container'      => 'a',
        )
    );
?>
```

Tried to use `<a>` as the container, but that's printing:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Menu</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu</a></li>
    <li><a>Menu</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove that entire `<ul><li>` structure. My menu should be printed as:

```html
<a>Menu</a>
<a>Menu</a>
```

I’ve also tried the following, which removes the `<ul>` tag, but `<li>` is still there:

```php
<?php
function wp_nav_menu_no_ul() {
    $options = array(
        'echo'           => false,
        'container'      => false,
        'theme_location' => 'api-footer-main',
        'fallback_cb'    => 'fall_back_menu'
    );
    
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( $options );
    echo preg_replace( array(
        '#^<ul[^>]*>^<li[^>]*>#',
        '#</li></ul>$#'
    ), '', $menu );
}

function fall_back_menu() {
    return;
}
```

And I'm calling that using `<?php wp_nav_menu_no_ul(); ?>`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to use a nav walker.

Comment: This doesn’t even make sense … Menus usually contain links, and links can not be nested in HTML. No clue what you even mean here, please clarify your question.

Comment: Do you have a wrong understanding of what `container` means, maybe? This is something WP will put _around_ the generated menu. If you want to output your menu _after_ an existing link, then you should place it into the correct location in your template file.

Comment: Do you just want a bunch `<a>` tags without the `<ul>` and `<li>` stuff? Is that your question?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes , you are right but please note i want add custom class also for <a class="test">menu</a>

Comment: I would recommend looking at [`wp_get_nav_menu_items`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/). That will give you an array of items that you can loop over and do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try to use the `strip_tags` php function, for example:

```
$options = array(
        'echo' => false,
        'container' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'api-footer-main',
        'fallback_cb'=> 'fall_back_menu'
    );
echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $options ), '<a>' );
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-li-elements-from-output-of-wp_nav_menu/)

For adding the `class` add the code below in function.php:

```
function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
   return preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="some-class"', $ulclass);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclass');
```

Comment: Tried this , but unable to add class to <a> tag,if i use following code
function add_link_atts($atts) {
    $atts['class'] = "nav-link";
    return $atts;
  }
  add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_link_atts');

It will add class a tag of all menus

Comment: @XavierIssac check please this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180688/how-to-add-class-to-link-in-wp-nav-menu