# How to add classes to <li> tags in WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing my WordPress theme from scratch. I can not work out how to add custom classes to the < li > tags as well as the classes generated by WordPress. Here is the code I currently have.

```
                    <nav class="navbar">
                        <?php
                        wp_nav_menu(
                            array(
                                'theme_location' => 'header',
                                'container' => 'ul',
                                'menu_class' => 'navbar__nav-list',
                            )
                        );
                        ?>
                    </nav>
```

What I am trying to achieve is the code example below.

```
 <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar__nav-list">
        <li class="navbar__nav-item">
            <a href="#">link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

How do I add custom classes to the < li > tags in my WordPress generated menu?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464505/how-to-add-class-in-li-using-wp-nav-menu-in-wordpress#answer-51665395

Comment: You should use the arg walker to built your menu structure. Read more about it here - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#comment-content-207 . At line 67 you will see how to implement li classes depending on the depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach your need using frontend methods or backend methods.

Frontend, using jQuery library, you can do the following:

```
$('nav.navbar .navbar__nav-list > li').addClass('navbar__nav-item');
```

Backend, using NavWalker class, you can include this class in your Functions.php file or on a separate file and include the file in Functions.php. The class looks like the following:

```
class NavWalker extends \Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Starts the element output. (the <li>)
     *
     * @param string $output the 
     * @param object $item the post object (nav_element) and contains props such as title, url, classes[], current:bool.
     * @param integer $depth
     * @param object $args the main menu arguments such as walker->has_children, container, container_class
     * @param integer $id
     * @return void
     */
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
    {
        $li_classes = implode(' ', $item->classes);
        $li_classes .= $depth === 0 ? ' navbar__nav-item': ''; // so you can target only the first parent <li>

        
        $output .= <<<EOD
        <li class="$li_classes">
            <a href="$item->url">
                $item->title
            </a>
        EOD;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the <li>
     *
     * same arguments description
     * @return void
     */
    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null)
    {
        $output .= '</li>';
    }

    /**
     * Starts the list (<ul>). It will be invoked only if the $depth is greater than 1.
     *
     * @param string $output
     * @param integer $depth
     * @param object $args the main menu arguments such as walker->has_children, container, container_class
     * @return void
     */
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        
        $output .= <<<EOD
        <ul class="navbar__nav-list">
        EOD;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the list (<ul>). It will be invoked only if the $depth is greater than 1.
     *
     * @param string $output
     * @param integer $depth
     * @param object $args the main menu arguments such as walker->has_children, container, container_class
     * @return void
     */
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $output .= <<<EOD
        </ul>
        EOD;
    }
}
```

And then you need to add the nav walker argument as following:

```
<nav class="navbar">
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'header',
            'container' => 'ul',
            'menu_class' => 'navbar__nav-list',
            'walker'          => new NavWalker(),
            )
    );
?>
</nav>
```